# Declaring priority_queue for user-defined class

Tags: c++, pointers, priority-queue

I have a class named Customer which is overloading the < operator:

```
bool Customer::operator<(const Customer &other) {
    return this->price < other.price;
}
```

but when I try to initialize the priority queue I get pages of errors.

```
Customer c1(10,5,12,30);// last parameter is price
Customer c2(10,5,12,2);
priority_queue<Customer , vector<Customer> , less<Customer> > barQ;
barQ.push(c2);
barQ.push(c1);
cout<<barQ.top().price;
```

Then, i accidentally found out that when i initialize it in following way:

```
Customer c1(10,5,12,30);
Customer c2(10,5,12,2);
priority_queue<Customer* , vector<Customer*> , less<Customer*> > barQ;
barQ.push(&c2);
barQ.push(&c1);
cout<<barQ.top()->price;
```

I got no errors and it works well.
So my question is that what's the difference between Customer & Customer*? 
I thought it should work when I declare it with Customer, NOT Customer* , why it works otherwise?

Comment: `operator<` should be const. The second version of your code has different meaning.

Comment: Or non-member function, if I recall it correctly.

Comment: You define a less-than operator for the `Customer` class, not for *pointers* to `Customer`. `Customer` and `Customer*` are two very different types.

Comment: That's exactly what i don't understand @Some programmer dude.             As you said , i defined a less-than operator for the **Customer** not pointers but it works when i call it with pointers

Comment: The problem is that then the priority queue is sorted by the *pointers*. You can compare pointers using the built-in `<` operator. Try changing the order in which you define `c1` and `c2` and it might not "work" anymore.

Comment: "it works" can only mean that you didnt really test it. The `less<Customer*>` is not using your `operator<`

Comment: @Incomputable those arent really alternatives, if it is a non-member it is also is required to accept a `const Customer`

Comment: @tobi303, yeah, forgot to mention that. It's just that I got used to const-correctness, so it didn't really seem important to mention for me.

Comment: I got the point, thanks for you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `std::less::operator()` is (taken from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)):

> ```
> bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;   // (until C++14)
> constexpr bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const; //(since C++14)
> ```

Note the it takes both parameters as `const`, thus it can only call a `const` `operator<`:

```
bool Customer::operator<(const Customer &other) const {  // <--- add const here
    return this->price < other.price;
}
```

Your second code is not really doing what you want it to do, because it uses the built-in `operator<` for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `const` in `operator` overload

```
bool operator<(const Customer &other) const {
        return this->price < other.price;
    }
```

you can also use your own comparator instead of `std::less`. Here is how we can write it.

```
template<typename type>
struct mycomp {
    bool operator()(const type & first, const type & second) const  {
        return first.price < second.price;
    }
};

struct Customer {
    int price;
};

int main(){
    Customer c1{3};// last parameter is price
    Customer c2{2};

    priority_queue<Customer , vector<Customer> , mycomp<Customer> > barQ;
    barQ.push(c2);
    barQ.push(c1);
    cout<<barQ.top().price;

    return 0;
}
```

`set::less<>` doesn't gives an error with `Customer*` pointer because pointers comparisons can happen as `int` and it doesn't look for the custom implementation. which is not the case with `Customer`.